# 5 commits made to wrong branch and pushed to remote/origin

Tags: git, github

So I accidentally made 5 commits to branch "A", but I intended to make it to branch "B". I have also pushed all my commits to the remote/origin. I realized that I have made all commits to wrong branch. Is there any way I can transfer all these 5 commits to branch "B" and make my branch "A" as it was 5 commits ago?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Checkout to `A`. Copy and paste the 5 commit hashes anywhere sequentially.

e.g. 5 (oldest) -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 (newest), assume 1 is your top commit of `git log` command.

```
$ git checkout A
$ git log
# copy the 5 commit hashes
```

Checkout to `B` and take (*cherry-pick*) 5 commits into `B` branch.

```
$ git checkout B

$ git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
# repeat 5 times with new commit hash each time (old to new)

# Or, you can cherry-pick a range of commits by 'git cherry-pick <from-commit>^..<to-commit>', note '^' sign
$ git cherry-pick <commit-5>^..<commit-1>
```

Now, Undo (`hard reset`) the latest 5 commits from `A`. Note, hard reset will change your A's git history (if there is anyone else pulled A branch already locally then you can use `revert` instead `hard reset`). so, **force** push is needed to push the branch `A`.

```
$ git checkout A
$ git branch A.bac           # backup branch 'A' for safety 

$ git reset --hard HEAD~5    # undo last 5 commits from branch A
$ git push -f origin HEAD    # need force push since history is changed
```

---

**Note:** The basic form of cherry picking a range of commits is:

```
$ git cherry-pick abc1234..def5678
```

`abc1234` is the oldest commit and `def5678` is the newest commit. `abc1234` is not included in the commit but `def5678` is included. If you want to include `abc1234` then start the range from the previous commit of `abc1234` by putting a `^` after `abc1234` like:

```
$ git cherry-pick abc1234^..def5678
```

Comment: Chery-picking interval of commits should start from the first to the last commit, if you wish to preserve the history as it is.

Comment: @kuskmen, `git cherry-pick A..B` here `A` should be older than `B`. Do you mean something other?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that when you say commit 5 I imagine that commit was pushed last which is effectively most recent one of other 4

Comment: Also note that if any commits come in between those 5 (for example by merge) cherry-picking range will have them too.

Comment: Ok. "assume 1 is your top commit of 'git log' command" here I mentioned 1 is the latest commit.

Comment: my bad I was reading the post from mobile phone and it was hard to notice, still, I think it is counterintuitive.

Comment: @SajibKhan where do I find documentation for git branch A.bac (backup) ?

Comment: here, `git branch A.bac` just create a branch called A.bac = A. You can checkout that branch by `git checkout A.bac` later if you need.